# formating issue while reading ASCI file having special character in it

Tags: asp.net

I am using the code below to read a CSV file:

```
TextReader tr = File.OpenText(path of the file);
```

This line of code is working when the CSV file does not contain any special character. However when the csv file contains any special character then the above line of code not able to read the special characters properly. when the file values with special characters are read and shown in the datagrid the characters appear as squares.

Now when I convert the file encoding to UTF-8 then it is working properly.

I have change the code like below to read the file with any encoding as below:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path of the file, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, true);
```

But this line of code is also not working.

Do any one have any idea to deal with this issue?

Comment: What do you mean by special character? Can you provide an example of a CSV file? Also please don't tell me that you are manually parsing a CSV file using string.Split.

Comment: special character means the characters which are not in english but in some other languages like chinese, japanese etc. Also I am not parsing the csv file manually, I am reading the file from a location in the disk.

Answer (score 0):

[Stop Rolling Your Own CSV Parser](http://secretgeek.net/csv_trouble.asp).

Comment: I am able to solve this problem of special character using the following line of code to read the file: StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path of the file, Encoding.Default);